# mina deploy undefined method set_default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mina

I have been trying to upgrade our app from Rails 3 to Rails 4.2.4 and have everything working minus being able to deploy. I can run rails server and console correctly, but run into an issue on the deploy.

The exact error is:

`` mina aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `set_default' for main:Object
path/config/deploy.rb:6:in `require'
path/config/deploy.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
path/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/mina:23:in `load'
path/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/mina:23:in `<top (required)>'
path/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
path/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>' ``

deploy.rb file

`require 'mina/bundler'
require 'mina/rails'
require 'mina/git'
require 'mina/rbenv'
require 'mina_sidekiq/tasks'
require 'mina/unicorn' #line 6`

Gemfile

`gem 'mina'
gem 'mina-sidekiq', :require => false
gem 'mina-unicorn', :require => false`

The only thing I was able to find was the `:require => false` in the Gemfile, which we already had.

Any ideas on where to investigate from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your mina is a version 1.0.0 but mina-sidekiq and unicorn have not updated to the newest version.

Either create your own sidekiq and unicorn tasks or downgrade mina to 0.3.8

Comment: Thank you. This was indeed the issue and I found it shortly before noticing your comment. Appreciate the help and definitely the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

mina-sidekiq has been updated and version 1.0 now requires Mina 1.0. Also fixes this issue :)

ref.: https://github.com/Mic92/mina-sidekiq

```
bundle update mina-sidekiq
```